# Add swf file in sbt process

Tags: flash, sbt

How to add file from a maven repo to my sbt compile / pack process. I have this build.sbt

name := "A Project"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.1"

sbtVersion := "0.12.3"

resolvers += "Typesafe snapshots" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/"

resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots2" at "https://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/forge"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.9.1" % "test", "com.adobe.flex.framework" % "core" % "4.5.0.18623"
)

sbt run 
...
[info] downloading https://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/forge/com/adobe/flex/framework/core/4.5.0.18623/core-4.5.0.18623.swc
...
but i dont found the swf file in my project....

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"i dont found the swf file in my project."*? I don't seem to understand. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want integrate the swf in my classpath, if I wrtie retrieveManaged := true, a directory lib_managed is created with all lib (swfs, jars ...). I need that core-4.5.0.18623.swc is copied into specifiy directory